# check if a record was inserted/updated/deleted in/from oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am exploring a database and I thought to find the tables that were recently updated through insert, update or delete statements in Oracle SQL developer. I have this query but it only shows the last_ddl_time which I don't want. Any idea.

```
select t1.owner, t1.object_name, t1.last_ddl_time from all_objects t1
where t1.owner = 'db_name'
order by created desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flashback Data Archive. This tracks all changes to tables for you automatically!

To use it, just create an archive and add your tables to it:

```
create flashback archive app_archive 
  tablespace users retention 7 year;
 
alter table customer_addresses 
  flashback archive app_archive;

You can then see changes as far back as the retention time using flashback query. For example:

/* What did the data look like yesterday? */
select * 
from   customer_addresses as of timestamp sysdate - 1;

/* What between yesterday and now? */
select * 
from   customer_addresses 
         versions between timestamp sysdate - 1 and sysdate;
```

Comment: Here is an excellent writeup. https://paulzipblog.wordpress.com/2021/05/03/auditing-table-data-changes-a-better-approach-flashback-data-archive/

Comment: Thanks for the input. Question though, does this work for the future updates once I add a table in flashback?

Comment: Yes. I would very much suggest you read up on the feature and its capabilities, including the link I attached before turning it on. This includes testing in some development environment first to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Looks like this needs to be set up before I can use it. Unfortunately, I only have read access to this database and can't use this approach but good to know this can be done. Thanks @Pugzly